# Using second router to avoid sky sr102 controlling DHCP

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, ip-address

I have have Sky internet and am having problems with the Sky **SR102** router handing out IP addresses as we have *A LOT* of devices in the house, and even though the DHCP IP range (5 - 254), the sky router just stops handing out IP addresses until you disconnect a device or restart the router.

I have tried many different solutions including giving every device a fixed IP based upon MAC address in the **SR102**. This did not work.

In my latest attempt to try and get round this issue I am following this thread [here](https://forums.overclockers.co.uk/threads/2-routers-to-avoid-sky-sr102.18681817/) and want to set my second router (**TP Link WD8980**) up as the router which controls the DHCP, leaving the sky SR102 just to handle the fibre connection. I cannot connect to Sky broadband with the TP-link as even with the correct sky credentials sniffed via wireshark, it wont connect to Sky broadband as apparently Sky has a particular connection protocol.

So the specific post I have followed is this one... (substitute out **Archer C7** for my **WD8980**)

```
Sky router:
- Set a LAN address of 192.168.0.1 and subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.
- Turn off WIFI.
- Put 192.168.0.2 in the DMZ.
- Reserve the IP address of 192.168.0.2 for the MAC address of the WAN interface of the Archer C7.
- Leave DHCP on.

Archer C7:
- Leave the WAN address as DHCP.
- Set a LAN address of 192.168.1.1 and subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.
- Set a DHCP scope of 192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.200 (or whatever you want to) along with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0.

The reason for leaving the DHCP server on on the Sky router and using a reservation for the Archer is so that if you have problems, you can wire in a computer to the Sky router and get a DHCP address and see if you have connectivity - thus ruling the C7 in or out as being the problem.

Setting up in this way will also allow you to get to the Sky router's web interface from a computer connected to the C7.

The C7 will effectively see the Sky network as the WAN interface, and Sky will see the C7 as being in the DMZ.
```

So I have followed this but I am sure that anything that connects to my network is using the **SKY SR102** to obtain its IP address, not the **WD8980** as all devices seem to be using the fixed IP addresses which I had previously set up for device MAC addresses on the **SKY SR102**, rather than any IP address in the range for the **WD8980** - which should be 100 - 254.

**Questions:**

- Is this the correct approach for what I am trying to do, or is there a much better way?
- Is there a definitive way to tell which router is the one
  handing out the IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats a good way and its the way I do it - different routers than yours. (A telstra router and a TPLink)

As to whihc machine you are getting the IP address from the answer is for a windows machine IPCONFIG /ALL will have a line

```
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

If it says that - then its the SKY router which responded - and that means you've cabled it wrong  as the sky router should only hand out addresses to devices on the LAN connections

So ensure

1. The WAN of the Sky router goes to the Internet
2. The WAN of the WD8980  goes to the LAN of the Sky Router
3. Nothing else connects to the LAN of the Sky Router
4. All your machines connect to the LAN of the WD8980

If you have a Linux box I can probably find how to get which DHCP server - but type IFCONFIG

Comment: Excellent - thank you.
I will confirm once I am back home and can take a look. I am pretty sure when I IPCONFIGed from my main machine it was DHCP showed the IP of the TPLink - which is good. 

I will double check router wiring and DHCP servers on a variety of devices and feed back the results

Comment: Just to confirm, this solution has appeared to work perfectly